# Yii add filter to a virtual attribute in CGridView and make it sortable

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I have the following Models :

`User` with columns {id,user_name,password,user_type}

`Admin` with columns {id,user_id,full_name,.....etc}

`Editor` with columns {id, user_id,full_name,...etc}

and the relations are
`User` : `'admin' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Admin', 'user_id'),'editor' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Editor', 'user_id'),`

`Admin` : `'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),`

`Editor` : `'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),`

Now i had setup a virtual attribute `fullName` in `User` Model as below

```
public function getFullName()

{

    if($this->user_type=='admin')

        return $this->admin->full_name;

    else if($this->user_type=='editor')

        return $this->editor->full_name;


}
```

I can show the virtual attribute , `fullName` , in a gridview , But how do i add a filter to the attribute and make it sortable in the gridview?

**UPADTE 1:**

I updated the models search() function as per the answer by @Jon as shown below

```
    public function search()
        {


            $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->select=array('*','COALESCE( editor.full_name,admin.first_name, \'\') AS calculatedName');
            $criteria->with=array('editor','admin');
            $criteria->compare('calculatedName',$this->calculatedName,true);
            $criteria->compare('email',$this->email,true);
            $criteria->compare('user_type',$this->user_type);

            return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,


));
    }
```

The names of both admins and editors are shown correctly in the gridview. But when i do a search through the filter the following exception occurs,

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'calculatedName' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `user` `t`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `editor` `editor` ON (`editor`.`user_id`=`t`.`id`)  LEFT OUTER JOIN `admin` `admin` ON (`admin`.`user_id`=`t`.`id`)  WHERE (calculatedName LIKE :ycp0) (C:\xampplite\htdocs\yii\framework\db\CDbCommand.php:528)</p><pre>#0 C:\xampplite\htdocs\yii\framework\db\CDbCommand.php(425):
```

How can I get rid of this?

UPDATE 2:
My mistake. It works fine when i changed the line

```
$criteria->compare('calculatedName',$this->calculatedName,true);
```

to

```
$criteria->compare('COALESCE( editor.full_name,admin.first_name, \'\')',$this->calculatedName,true);
```

and btw thanx @Jon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is effectively add a calculated column to the result set. Imagine that in the SQL query used to fetch the results you will be joining both the `Admin` and `Editor` tables, so `Admin.full_name` and `Editor.full_name` are the two columns that will be involved in calculating the desired value.

Since at least one `Admin.full_name` and `Editor.full_name` is always going to be `NULL`, the formula to calculate the final value would be

```
COALESCE(Admin.full_name, Editor.full_name, '')
```

Now that you have the calculated formula, you need to take these steps:

1. Add a read-write column to your model to receive the calculated column
2. Create a `CDbCriteria` that joins the two tables and includes the calculated column
3. Create a `CSort` that describes how the calculated column should affect the record order
4. Create a `CActiveDataProvider` that uses these criteria and sort options
5. Feed the data provider to your `CGridView`

So, first add a public property to the model:

```
public $calculatedName;
```

And then:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
    'select' => array(
        '*',
        'COALESCE(Admin.full_name, Editor.full_name, \'\') AS calculatedName',
    ),
    'with'   => array('Admin', 'Editor'),
    // other options here
));

$sort = new CSort;
$sort->attributes = array(
    'calculatedName' => array(
        'asc'  => 'COALESCE(Admin.full_name, Editor.full_name, \'\')',
        'desc' => 'COALESCE(Admin.full_name, Editor.full_name, \'\') DESC',
    ),
    // other sort order definitions here
);

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
    'criteria' => $criteria,
    'sort'     => $sort,
));
```

And finally, use `$dataProvider` to populate your grid; use `calculatedName` as the column name.

Apologies if I got some detail wrong, as I did not actually run this.

**Update:** It turns out that Yii doesn't like it if you specify `CDbCriteria.select` as a string and that string contains any commas not used to separate columns (such as the commas used to separate the arguments to `COALESCE`). Thankfully `CDbCriteria` also allows passing in the columns as an array, which gets around this problem. I updated the code above to match.

For anyone who's curious, the offending code is [this](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/db/ar/CActiveFinder.php#931).

Comment: I don't know I'm doing anything wrong but i keep getting this error CDbException:Active record "User" is trying to select an invalid column "COALESCE( admin.full_name". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias..

Comment: @dInGd0nG: You are doing nothing wrong, the answer I posted just ran afoul of one of Yii's little quirks. See update.

Comment: okey. The update works well. But i cant use `$criteria->compare('fullName',$this->calculatedName,true);` as when i do a search in the CGridView filter the following Exception occures 
<p>CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'calculatedName' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `user` `t`  LEFT OUTER JOIN `editor` `editor` ON (`editor`.`user_id`=`t`.`id`)  LEFT OUTER JOIN `admin` `admin` ON (`admin`.`user_id`=`t`.`id`)  WHERE (calculatedName LIKE :ycp0)

Comment: @dInGd0nG: It would be helpful if you posted the relevant code as an update to the question. Anyway I think that to filter on the column you need to add it manually, e.g. `$criteria->condition = "COALESCE (...) LIKE '%$var%'"`, substituting an appropriate quoted expression for `$var`. Calculated columns sure are a lot of trouble.