# CDbCriteria with virtual model attribute

Tags: php, mysql, yii, model

I'm using CDbCriteria to filter a CListView (Products page)

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->join ='LEFT JOIN collections ON collections.id = t.collection_id';

    (isset($_GET['name'])) ? $name = $_GET['name'] : $name = "";
    $criteria->addCondition('t.name LIKE :name');
    $criteria->params = array(':name' => "%$name%");
    $criteria->order = 't.name asc';

    //get count
    $count = Products::model()->count($criteria);
```

But the problem: In the products model I have a virtual attribute named ProductFinalPrice what calculates the final price based on user role & product category and user specific product price.

How can I sort by this virtual attribute?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a simple virtual attribute which can be calculated by the database you need to define the attribute with a `SELECT [...] AS virtual attribute_name`.
[Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/38869-cgridview-sort-by-virtual-attribute/), [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/18589-how-to-have-a-sortable-virtual-attribute-in-a-grid/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10890507/yii-sort-by-a-custom-attribute) is a topic on that.

If you have a more complicated calculation which is a method in your model, you cannot use `CActiveDataprovider`. Best would be to use `CArrayDataprovider` which can use virtual attributes. I'm sorry, I cannot find a good example for that at the moment.

Be aware that `CArrayDataprovider` is somewhat unperformant, so you are best to avoid it whenever you can and do your best to put the calculation of that virtual attribute in the sql of `CDbCriteria`.