# Order a CGridView by a specific method on a model

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a `CGridView` which calls `search` (AFAIK) on the given model to fetch the list of models to display. Is it possible to order the result of said view by the result of calling `$model->some_method()`?

I've read a bunch of similar questions and they all pretty much recommend to duplicate what the code does in SQL, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10472732/493122). The problem is that the `some_method` is much more complicated and cannot be written in SQL.

I've also read about [virtual attributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/), which would fit nicely, but if I write:

```
public function getSomeMethod() { ... }
```

and then use:

```
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination'=>false,
        'sort' => array(
            'attributes' => array('somemethod'),
            'defaultOrder' => array(
                'somemethod' => CSort::SORT_ASC,
            )
        )
    ));
```

it gives me:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.somemethod' in 'order clause'.
>   The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `use_case` `t` ORDER BY
>   `t`.`somemethod`

What should I do?

Comment: Probably you need  CArrayDataProvider, because your attributes doesn't exist on your sql query/table. With ArrayDataProvider you can build your custom dataset with real and virtual attributes

Answer (score 0):

The defaultOrder array content must be an array of columns related to the CSort::ConstantValue ..

see yii1 doc http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSort#defaultOrder-detail

```
'attributes'=>array(
'price'=>array(
    'asc'=>'item.price',
    'desc'=>'item.price DESC',
    'label'=>'Item Price',
    'default'=>'desc',
),
'*',
)
```

Then if you need sort for a method result  you simply set this  result in proper column and the set this column name in array ..

If you don't can define the method like a sql statement you can't use the order of the dataprovider

the problem is that the default order and in general the order are clause managed by sql and not by yii or php then if you can't define the method  like sql element you can't use this for ordering in dataProvider .. essentially dataProvider in a sql manager .

Comment: Could you please expand on the last statement? I don't quite understand what you mean with "simply set this result in proper column and the set this column name in array".

Comment: Ok.  eg: If your method can be applied to the columns data then you can use sql for calculate this value and returnit  like an alias column  that you can show in gridview ordered properly by defalutOrder setting

Comment: From the question body: "The problem is that `some_method` is much more complicated and cannot be written in SQL."

Comment: Then just a suggestion try ... using getSomeMethod instead of someMethod in attribute and defaultOrder ..Obviosly the getSomeMethod is in model ... right?

Comment: Right after the part I've quoted, in the question, I explain how I have tried with `getSomeMethod` and how I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: Two suggestion  1 ) Looking at you dataProvider code i see  'somemethod' but in your function you have getSomeMethod this is for 'someMethod'  and 2) i suggest you to use the explicit function name and not the getter name ... alias 'attributes' => array('getSomeMethod') and  'getSomeMethod' => CSort::SORT_ASC, ... i hope my comment is clear ..

Comment: Same problem both trying with `someMethod` and `getSomeMethod`.

Comment: I'm sorry ... this i correct ...the problem is that the default order and in general the order are clause manageed by sql and not by yii or php then if you can define this like sql element you can't use for orderining in dataProvider .. essentially dataProvider in a sql manager ... i update the answer with this comment for other user too